# Is it possible to return Two dimensional JSON Array in BigQuery function

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to form below Solution in BigQuery function.

My data format:

```
{
  "column1" : "test1",
  "column2" : "test2", 
  "column3" ": [{'field1': 'a', 'field2': 'b'}, {'field1': 'c', 'field2': 'd'}]
}
```

Expecting Solution:

```
{
  "column1" : "test1",
  "column2" : "test2", 
  "column3" ": [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
}
```

Based on below solution, I have implemented a Javascript function to form the expected array payload. But, with RETURN type I am not able to configure ARRAY<ARRAY>

Implemented Function:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION JsonToItems(items ARRAY<STRUCT<a STRING, b STRING>>)
RETURNS ARRAY<ARRAY<STRING>> (<--- Not able to return this)
LANGUAGE js AS r"""
  console.log(items);
  var arr_1 = [];
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var arr_2 = [];
        var keys = Object.keys(items[i]);
        for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
            arr_2.push(items[i][keys[j]]);
        }
        arr_1.push(arr_2);
    }
  
  return arr_1;
""";
```

If anyone have thoughts regarding on how to approach the above solution please let me know.. thanks

https://medium.com/google-cloud/transforming-nested-jsons-into-an-array-of-structs-in-bigquery-514988506384

Comment: Unfortuntely, an array of array is not supported in BigQuery.

Comment: Hi @Ravindra Bakkamanthala , BigQuery does not support array of array but you can create a array of structs as mentioned in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#building_arrays_of_arrays). Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Jaytiger  @Shipra Sarkar for your inputs. I have implemented on changing temp function from `return arr_1` to `return JSON.stringify(arr_1)` and changed to `RETURNS STRING` which fixed my issue.

Comment: Hi @RavindraBakkamanthala, Can you post your answer so that it will help the community members with their research as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my issue on returning JSON string.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION JsonToItems(items ARRAY<STRUCT<a STRING, b STRING>>)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS r"""
  var arr_1 = [];
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var arr_2 = [];
        var keys = Object.keys(items[i]);
        for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
            arr_2.push(items[i][keys[j]]);
        }
        arr_1.push(arr_2);
    }
  
  return JSON.stringify(arr_1);
""";
```